# File upload to create directory ASP.Net core mac os doesn't create sub folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using asp.net core to create a project to upload the file in specific location in the server.

Here is the code:

```
TempFileName = Regex.Replace(vehicle.FileUpload.FileName, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+", "_", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var directiveToUpload = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images\\UploadFile");

if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(directiveToUpload))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(directiveToUpload);
}

await SaveFileToServer(TempFileName);
```

Save the file:

```
async Task SaveFileToServer(string FileName)
{

    if (vehicle.FileUpload.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(directiveToUpload, FileName), FileMode.Create))
        {
            await vehicle.FileUpload.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Since the file Get uploaded But it doesn't create sub folder on mac. **images\UploadFile** this is not working.

[image: image upload]

Comment: wondering if you need to create the folder structure first with something like: System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
file.Directory.Create(); this handles nested folders and doesn't do anything if the folder already exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't reproduce this issue, but since directory separator is not \ on Mac, I guess it does not interpret it correctly. You could replace your code with the usage of `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` constant to avoid this.

```
var directiveToUpload = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images\\UploadFile");
```

Would become

```
var directiveToUpload = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, $"images{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}UploadFile");
```

Comment: Thanks that was the issue